# Http Adapter Invocation failure?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters

The Control is going to failure function when I'm trying to invoke Http Adapter.Here My adapter is running fine and I'm getting data also.

Here is My html code

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>IIB_WL_App</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="images/apple-touch-icon.png">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/IIB_WL_App.css">
<script>window.$ = window.jQuery = WLJQ;</script>
</head>
<body id="content" style="display: none;">
<form name="f1">
Enter Employee ID :<input type="text" id="EmpId">
<br>
<input type="submit" value="GetDetails" onclick="GetDetails()">
</form>
<!--application UI goes here-->
<script src="js/initOptions.js"></script>
<script src="js/IIB_WL_App.js"></script>
<script src="js/messages.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is My .js code For getting details

```
function GetDetails(){
//alert("Function Called");
var id=f1.EmpId.value;
//var id=document.getElementById("EmpId").value();
alert(id);
var invocationData = {
    adapter : 'IIB_WL_Adapter',
    procedure : 'getData',
    parameters : [id]
};
var options={
        onSuccess : getDataSuccess,
        onFailure : getDataFailure, 
};
WL.Client.invokeProcedure(invocationData,options);

};
function getDataSuccess(result) {
//WL.Logger.debug("Retrieve success" +  JSON.stringify(result));

alert("Success");
var httpStatusCode = result.status;
alert(httpStatusCode);

}
function getDataFailure(result) {
//WL.Logger.debug("Retrieve success" +  JSON.stringify(result));
alert("Failure");
   var httpStatusCode = result.status;
   alert(httpStatusCode);    
}
```

And I want to display that data in a list view

Here is MY adapter.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Licensed Materials - Property of IBM 5725-G92 (C) Copyright IBM Corp. 
2011, 2013. All Rights Reserved. US Government Users Restricted Rights - 
Use, duplication or disclosure restricted by GSA ADP Schedule Contract with 
IBM Corp. -->
<wl:adapter name="IIB_WL_Adapter" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:wl="http://www.worklight.com/integration" xmlns:http="http://www.worklight.com/integration/http">

<displayName>IIB_WL_Adapter</displayName>
<description>IIB_WL_Adapter</description>
<connectivity>
    <connectionPolicy xsi:type="http:HTTPConnectionPolicyType">
        <protocol>http</protocol>
        <domain>172.17.14.228</domain>
        <port>7080</port>
        <!-- Following properties used by adapter's key manager for choosing specific 
            certificate from key store <sslCertificateAlias>       </sslCertificateAlias> <sslCertificatePassword></sslCertificatePassword> -->
    </connectionPolicy>
    <loadConstraints maxConcurrentConnectionsPerNode="2" />
</connectivity>

<procedure name="getData" />
```

Here is My adpater-impl.js

```
function getData(interest) {
//path = getPath(interest);

var input = {
    method : 'get',  
    path : '/DBRetrive',
    returnedContentType : 'xml',
    parameters : {'id' : interest}  
};


return WL.Server.invokeHttp(input);
```

}

Comment: What is the failure message? add it to the question.

Comment: The Control is going to getDataFailure function. I kept alert message "failure". It is not going to getDataSuccess Function

Comment: Instead of printing "failure", print the actual result: result.errorMsg. What is the error?

Comment: The errorMsg is "The Service Currently not available". But My adapter is running fine.

Comment: {
   "Employee": {
      "Data": {
         "AGE": "25",
         "ID": "2168",
         "NAME": "Trinadh"
      }
   },
   "errors": [
   ],
   "info": [
   ],
   "isSuccessful": true,
   "responseHeaders": {
      "Content-Length": "80",
      "Content-Type": "text\/xml;charset=utf-8",
      "Date": "Fri, 08 May 2015 11:42:19 GMT",
      "Server": "Apache-Coyote\/1.1"
   },
   "responseTime": 13846,
   "statusCode": 200,
   "statusReason": "OK",
   "totalTime": 14143,
   "warnings": [
   ]
} // This is my adapter's output. The same details I want to display on mobile

Comment: I added my .xml file and imp.js files. This is what your asking about

Comment: At present I'm  testing on My Browser. "Preview as common resource".

Comment: Is your device connected to the same WiFi network as your Worklight Server?

Comment: no no in browser also it is failing

Comment: You wrote that there are times it works. Where does it work then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the solution for this problem. The problem is in my Html page i.e instead of using this.

```
<input type="submit" value="GetDetails" onclick="GetDetails()">
```

use the following tag with button type then its working.

```
<input type="button" value="GetDetails" onclick="return GetDetails()">
```

And for displaying the data I added some code in .js file

```
function GetDetails(){
var id=f1.EmpId.value;
alert(id);
var invocationData = {
    adapter : 'IIB_WL_Adapter',
    procedure : 'getData',
    parameters : [id]
};
var options={
        onSuccess : getDataSuccess,
        onFailure : getDataFailure, 
};
WL.Client.invokeProcedure(invocationData,options);

};
function getDataSuccess(result) {
   display(result.invocationResult.Employee.Data);
}
function getDataFailure(result) {
   alert(JSON.stringify(result));
   alert(result.errorMsg);
   var httpStatusCode = result.status;
}
function display(items){

var ul=$("#itemList");
ul=$("#itemList").html("&nbsp");
var li=$('<li/>').html("Id:"+items.ID);
li.append($('<li/>').html("Name:"+items.NAME));
li.append($('<li/>').html("Age:"+items.AGE));
ul.append(li);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've ran your code.
The code itself appears to be sound.

It's failing though, so I don't understand what do you mean by "The Control is going to failure function when I'm trying to invoke Http Adapter.Here My adapter is running fine and I'm getting data also."

You say you tested it in the browser and it is failing with "The Service Currently not available". It is also failing the same for me in the browser, and also the same when invoking the adapter from the Studio - same error message.

So again, *where* exactly is it working for you?

As I see it, the problem is in your adapter configuration, the location you're pointing to does not exist or is the wrong location to point to: http://172.17.14.228:7080/DBretrieve

Comment: Here the location  http://172.17.14.228:7080/DBretrieve is running fine. And this location wont work for you because it is in local network. While I'm running my Adapter It is working fine and I'm getting data in JSON format. Now I'm trying to invoke this adapter from my mobile UI i.e Html page which contains one text field and one button when click on button this adapter need to be call but I'm unable to call this adapter.